# How can we audit a field of an entity according to a condition?

Tags: hibernate-envers

To audit an entity conditionally, there is the option of using the Integrators and extends Envers event liteners.
But can we audit a field or a property conditionally ?

In our case , we have a blob column, and to avoid the increase of the volume of the audit tables , we want to set the value of this column only when a  condition is valid. Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated, the current and only way to do *Conditional Auditing* is to extend the Envers listeners as you described, register your custom ones via an Integrator and make sure to configure Envers not skip its event listener registration step.

As an example, lets assume you have extended `EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl`:

```
public class CustomPostUpdateEventListener extends EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl {
  @Override
  public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    if ( event.getEntity() instanceof YourCustomEntityType ) {
      if ( !isSpecialConditionSet( event ) ) {
        return;
      }
    }
    super.onPostUpdate( event );
  }

  private boolean isSpecialConditionSet(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    final Object conditionValue = event.getPersister()
        .getPropertyValue( event.getEntity(), "nameOfPropertyCondition" );
    /* check your condition and return true if you should not audit the entity */        
  }
}
```

One thing to consider when doing *Conditional Auditing* is when a `PostInsertEvent` for an entity is fired, it should **not** be considered conditional if you use the `ValidityAuditStrategy` to avoid downstream issues when you update that entity in a future transaction.